# Can't access maven repo through URLConnection or HttpsURLConnection (403)

Tags: java, web-scraping, maven-repository

*Purpose, just a POC (for now) to automatically and periodically find some CVE tags in the maven repository.*

I can access maven just fine through browser and mvn, but am unable to do the same via Java, what am I missing? I've tried UrlConnection, HttpsURLConnection, with and without GET, Content-type, User-Agent, and Accept, it always returns a 403 for all addresses that I try, the same code works fine on other websites like "cve.mitre.org" or "nvd.nist.gov", but fails for "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17".

My URL is been built dynamically, with the start "**[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/**"](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/**%22), then adding the group, name, and version are added, turning it into a valid address like "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17"

```
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "xxxx");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "xxxx");

    String content = null;
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(address);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

        con.connect();
        
        BufferedReader br;
        
        if (con.getResponseCode() < 300) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }            

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
```

Comment: Because it's explicitly trying to not be crawled and wants JS and a captcha.

Comment: NOOOO! There goes my dream of automating the most tedious and annoying task I have nowadays, anyone knows another good site to acquire CVE code or vulnerability code of the jars I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This web use anti-bot security **CloudFlare**.
How to **bypass** CloudFlare bot **protection**?
It depends.... Sometimes it is very **difficult** task or **impossible**. That you need to do, is simulate a real user with the browser.
With [htmlunit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/) browser you can bypass it in **this case only** and with a **good IP address**. (i use my own ip address and did only one request)

You need maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.57.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here you have some java example:

```java
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class Maven {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            URL target = new URL("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17");
            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(target);
            List<HtmlAnchor> elements = page.getByXPath("//a[contains(@class, 'vuln')]");
            elements.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.getTextContent()));
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
CVE-2022-23305
CVE-2022-23302
CVE-2021-4104
CVE-2019-17571
View 1 more ...
4 vulnerabilities
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, even though it worked ONCE in my private environment, I cannot use it for a batch process in my professional environment, but that's the answer to my question anyway.
Alternatively, I found that OWASP has a dependency check program, that can be used via console and gives a report, this report is quite ugly and hard to move around, but it has the CVEs I need. I'll use it as a base to create an automation algorithm.